# How to fish a rubber seal gasket from dryer exhaust

Tags: dryer, laundry

So I bought one of these vent hose (https://youtu.be/JwqfSEbhCwY) and yeah I should've read the reviews. Well, the rubber gasket fell into the dryer exhaust. I stuck my hand as far as it can go but I can't get to it. The exhaust turns down the wall and the there's a 90 degree elbow and runs out the back of the house.

Our dryer is throwing an error and I believe it's due to the clog. I confirmed this by running the dryer without the vent hose attached and it was fine. Would a dryer vent cleaning company be able to retrieve it?

Comment: Try bending a hanger and see if you can hook it..... try from inside and outside.

Comment: yep if I had one. I'm thinking a shop vac. will have to do this tomorrow once I have some time. I wonder if I made it worse by turning the dryer on. ugh.

Comment: Always get the gasket or whatever you dropped **before** turning it on again...

Comment: Do you have an idea of how long the duct is based on where it enters the wall and where it exits the house?